# Launch software from SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to open software (the .exe file of the software, like notepad.exe) by clicking on a link in SharePoint 2013. I don't want to open it in SharePoint; I just want to open the software which is installed on my PC through SharePoint.

Thanks in advance for your help,
Anna

Answer (score 1):

This will be blocked by browser sandboxing. There are delivery methods, such as [ClickOnce](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/clickonce-security-and-deployment), but they may not function for what you're attempting to do.